# Run external command in PowerShell for octopus deploy

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

We are using

```
Octopus.Migrator partial-export --project=Export Script --password=deploy1 --directory=D:\Export Script
```

to export project but this command only runs on OD server and we need to navigate  to:

```
C:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Octopus\Octopus.Migrator.exe
```

I am trying to automate this thing in PowerShell and I tried

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow 
              -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Octopus\Octopus.Migrator.exe" 
              -ArgumentList "Octopus.Migrator partial-export --project=Export Script --password=deploy1 --directory=D:\Export Script"
```

And also tried

```
$a = "C:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Octopus\Octopus.Migrator.exe"
$b = "Octopus.Migrator.exe partial-export --project=webapp_deploy1 --password=deploy1 --directory=D:\webapp_deploy1"
& $a $b
```

but none of these are working... can you please suggest what should I do?

Comment: $command = "C:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Octopus\Octopus.Migrator.exe"
$param = @('partial-export','--project=Export Script','--password=deploy1','--directory=D:\Export Script')
& $command $param >"D:\output.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Octopus Deploy team for helping me....
Solution was :
I had to remove `octopus.migrator` from `$param`.

```
$command = "C:\Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Octopus\Octopus.Migrator.exe"
$param = @('partial-export','--project=Export Script','--password=deploy1','--directory=D:\Export Script')
& $command $param >"D:\output.txt"
```